# How to arrange 100 html divs such that all of them are rotated toward a certain point

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to place some div elements(as seats) which are rotated toward a certain point. It's an theater hall website in which I have to show seats as boxes arranged on a curve in front of the theater scene.

I decided to absolute position seats and rotate them using Math.atan2. I can't figure out why rotation isn't working.

I tried this code:

```
let origin = document.getElementById("frontScene");
  let origin_position = origin.getBoundingClientRect();
  origin_position.x = origin_position.x + origin_position.width/2;
  origin_position.y = origin_position.y + origin_position.height/2;

  for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    
    let el = document.getElementById(i);

    let el_position = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    el_position.x = el_position.x + el_position.width/2;
    el_position.y = el_position.y + el_position.height/2;
    
    let calc_angle = Math.atan2(
      el_position.y - origin_position.y,
      el_position.x - origin_position.x
    );
    if (calc_angle < 0) {
    
      calc_angle += Math.PI * 2;
    
    }
    let rotation = calc_angle * (180 / Math.PI);
     el.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
  }
```

Comment: At first, you should check value of variable `rotation` and other variables using `console.log` or `alert` to see if they are calculated correctly.

Comment: They aren't calculated correctly and I'm still wondering where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Well it does seem to be working.

```js
let origin = document.getElementById("frontScene");
let origin_position = origin.getBoundingClientRect();
origin_position.x = origin_position.x + origin_position.width / 2;
origin_position.y = origin_position.y + origin_position.height / 2;

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {

  let el = document.getElementById(i);

  let el_position = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  el_position.x = el_position.x + el_position.width / 2;
  el_position.y = el_position.y + el_position.height / 2;

  let calc_angle = Math.atan2(
    el_position.y - origin_position.y,
    el_position.x - origin_position.x
  );
  if (calc_angle < 0) {

    calc_angle += Math.PI * 2;

  }
  let rotation = calc_angle * (180 / Math.PI);
  el.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
}
```

```css
.square {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="frontScene" class="square" style="margin: auto; background: red"></div>

<div id="1" class="square"></div>
<div id="2" class="square"></div>
<div id="3" class="square" style="margin-left: 120px"></div>
<div id="4" class="square"></div>
<div id="5" class="square"></div>
```